# Android: Displaying a hyperlink and image inside email's body

Tags: android, android-intent, android-activity

I am trying to open email activity and to display in the email's body the following:

1. Display a hyperlink to a web site.
2. Display (not attach) an image logo (.png file).

I tried using html/text/image mime type and nothing works for both things. 
I even tried to copy the png file to an sdcard and displaying it from sdcard path instead of using the "Assets" location that may be restricted and private only to the application, but it did not help as well! 
Can anyone give me a code which works for both things??

Waiting for you help guys!!

Comment: I'm afraid that you can't include an image in the Email Intent's body.

Comment: Thank you!! What about a hyperlink? is there a way to display a hyperlink?

Comment: I believe Gmail app supports plain text only (I don't know if there are other apps that do support rich formatting). So, I can say both images and hyperlinks are off the table. Sorry!

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried :

```
Linkify.addLinks(yourEmailString,  Linkify.WEB_URLS);
    yourTextView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

It will make all links in the message clickable, not sure if this is what you are searching though :)?

Comment: No, I did not try this.  if this is my code:

final Intent emailIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);

/* Fill it with Data */
emailIntent.setType("plain/text");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, new String[]{"to@email.com"});
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Subject");
emailIntent.putExtra(android.content.Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Text");

/* Send it off to the Activity-Chooser */
context.startActivity(Intent.createChooser(emailIntent, "Send mail..."));

how can I add Linkify to an email? I mean I do not use yourTextView.